# how to check equality of one value with two values?

Tags: python-3.x, string, operators, equality

if you look at the pseudo code, i am trying to make a new string without certain elements.

```
thesentence = 'i need help!*'
bettersentence = ''.join([char for char in thesentence if char != '!' and '*'])

print(bettersentence)
```

comparing a character with two strings at the same time doesnt work. But im wondering wether there isnt any easy approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your string into a list and then use a for loop to see which characters in the string equal to * or ! and replace them with an empty string

```
def bettersentence(text):
    text = list(text)
    for i, character in enumerate(text):
        if character == '*' or character == '!': 
            text[i] = ''
    return ('').join(text)
```

Comment: hey! This works I understand it perfectly. Thank you ^^